# How to modify the original setter function [adding some extra lines of logic to original function ]of HTMLSelectElement.prototype?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I want to modify the setters of HTML prototypes. In a way like adding some extra lines in original function. I found a deprecated code in online.

```js
function innerHTMLSetter(val){
                            /*
                            // Extra logic 
                            
                            */
           str =val.toString();   
           Components.lookupMethod(this,"innerHTML")(str?str:"");;
                             return val;
                           }
                            HTMLSelectElement.prototype.__defineSetter__("innerHTML",innerHTMLSetter );
```

Here Components.lookupMethod looks up a native method or property. Deprecated now.

Any suggestions on modifying the original setter function or any equivalent to Components.lookupMethod ?

Comment: "*I want to modify the setters of HTML prototypes*" - [I believe you don't](http://perfectionkills.com/whats-wrong-with-extending-the-dom/).